# Close CSS menu on iOS device

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, drop-down-menu

I am struggling with getting a css menu to close on iOS. The menu is displayed using :hover, so the div is set to block and is shown on screen. This displays fine on iOS so the menu is shown but if you click off the menu, just into blank space, the menu still stays. There seems to be no way to get this to hide and to remove the :hover state.

I have found out that if you click in a blank space (not on a link or any div with :hover or cursor:pointer set) on an iOS device then no click seems to be registered so I am guessing this is the main issue.

How can I fix this? Is there anything you can do to make css only menus work fine on iOS?

An example of the problem is here on the Choose a beach menu http://www.beachstays.com.au/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've used jQuery to mimic the css hover function for similar issues. Might be worth trying?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEtGy

```
$('.tohover').mouseover( function(){
  $(this).addClass('hover');
});

$('.tohover').mouseout( function(){
  $(this).removeClass('hover');
});
```